# How to capture all generated events with ftrace without any loss

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, trace, procfs, ftrace

I'm currently doing some experiments, and I need to record all the events that are generated during the execution of normal stress-ng execution cyle like this `/usr/bin/stress-ng -c 80 -t 30 --times --exec 50 --exec-ops 50`, specifically the ones related to exec (`sched:sched_process_exec` and `syscalls:sys_enter_execve`).
Unfortunately when analysing the trace file, I get some processes that didn't generated any `sys_execve`, but were captured by the `sched_process_exec`, which to me makes no sense.
This happened even though no events where lost (in the trace file the entries in buffer/written are the same, and trace-cmd doesn't warn about events lost).
Given this situation I can't understand why this happens, and the only explanation I can give is that these events are not being recorded. Any help would be appreciated.
[Here's an example for reference of trace file I get](https://pastebin.com/PvDaqTjv)

To be clear in what I'm saying, these lines should be the norm:

```
stress-ng-1748  [001] .... 19573.548553: sys_execve(filename: 7ffe7a791720, argv: 7ffe7a791700, envp: 7ffe7a7916f8)
stress-ng-1748  [001] .... 19573.548707: sched_process_exec: filename=/usr/bin/stress-ng pid=1748 old_pid=1748
```

A process which generated both the `sys_execve` event and the `sched_process_exec` event.

Whereas this one:

```
stress-ng-1780  [005] .... 19573.598398: sched_process_exec: filename=/usr/bin/stress-ng pid=1780 old_pid=1780
```

which is the last one of the file in the link, is an example of process without a `sys_execve` event associated.

Bonus question: I'd also need to record the equivalent fork event (namely `syscalls:sys_enter_fork`) with a stress execution with fork-ops (or something equivalent), but I haven't been able to do so, neither from trace-cmd, nor manually from Ftrace. I've read around the internet that there are some special cases when dealing with forking processes, but couldn't understand what to do in order to record this event in particular.
Any help on this matter would be appreciated as well.

Comment: please add something of file from link to answer

Comment: Is it better now @JanČerný?

Comment: definetly! Thank you for edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by also capturing the event `syscalls:sys_enter_execve`. Between the two of them I was able to get every instance of exec called.